# Fourier series: Proof of orthonormality and complex coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

First of all, I would like to apologise for my English. It is not my native language. I hope that you can understand everything.

I am currently having difficulties with Fourier series. Most of the problems I could already solve, but with one I am unsure and with another problem, I am unable to find the right approach. I would be very grateful if you could give me feedback on my solution for task 1 and hints on how to solve task 2.

I was given the following equations

\begin{align}
\phi_{ n } &= \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{ L } } e^{ ik_{ n }x }, & k &= \frac{ 2 n \pi }{ L }, & \langle \phi_{ n } \lvert \phi_{ m } \rangle &= \int_0^L{ \phi_{ n }(x)^{ * } \phi_{ m }(x)  dx = \delta_{ nm }}
\end{align}

and asked to

> 1. Show that the given basis is orthonormal.

**Solution**

For $m \neq n$

\begin{align}
\int_0^L { \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{ L } } e^{ -ik_{ n }nx } \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{ L } } e^{ ik_{ n }mx } dx } &= \frac{ 1 }{ L } \int_0^L{ e^{ ik_{ n }(m-n)x } dx} \\
&= \frac{ 1 }{ L } \left[ \frac{ 1 }{ ik_{ n }(m-n) } e^{ ik_{ n }(m-n)x } \right]^{ L }_{ 0 }
\end{align}

Next, using

$$e^{ ik_{ n }(m-n)x }=e^{ ik_{ n }ax }=e^{ in\frac{ 2\pi }{ L }aL }=e^{ ina2\pi }= \cos(2an\pi)+i \sin(2an\pi)=1$$

we have

$$\frac{ 1 }{ L } \left[ \frac{ 1 }{ ik_{ n }(m-n) } e^{ ik_{ n }(m-n)x } \right]^{ L }_{ 0 } = \frac{ 1 }{ L } \left(  \frac{ 1 }{ ik_{ n }(m-n) } (1-e^{ 0 })\right)=0$$

For $m=n$

\begin{align}
\int_0^L{ \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{ L } } e^{ -ik_{ n }nx } \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{ L } } e^{ ik_{ n }mx } dx } &= \frac{ 1 }{ L } \int_0^L{ e^{ ik_{ n }(m-n)x } dx} \\
&= \frac{ 1 }{ L }\int_0^L{ e^{ 0 }dx } \\
&= 1 \\
\end{align}

> 2. Show that for any function $f(x)$ that can be represented as a
>    linear combination of the basis functions $\phi_{ n }=\frac{ 1 }{
>    \sqrt{ L } } e^{ ik_{ n }x }$ i.e $$f(x) = \sum_{ n = -\infty }^{ \infty } { c_{ n } \phi_{ n } }$$ the complex Fourier coefficients $c_{ n }$ are
>    given by $c_{ n } = \langle \phi_{ n } \lvert f \rangle$.

$$f(x) = \sum_{ n = -\infty }^{ \infty } { c_{ n } \phi_{ n } } | *\phi_{ m }^*$$
$$f(x)*\phi_{ m }^* = \sum_{ n = -\infty }^{ \infty } { c_{ n } \phi_{ n } }\phi_{ m }^*$$
$$<\phi_{ m } | f>=\int_0^L{ \sum_{ n = -\infty }^{ \infty } { c_{ n } \phi_{ n } }\phi_{ m }^* dx } \\
= \sum_{ n = -\infty }^{ \infty } { c_{ n }} \int_0^L{ \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{ L } } e^{ -ik_{ n }mx }* \frac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{ L } } e^{ ik_{ n }nx } dx}\\
=\sum_{ n = -\infty }^{ \infty } { c_{ n }} * \frac{ 1 }{ L } \int_0^L{  e^{ ik_{ n }(n-m)x } dx }$$

From task 1 I know that for $m \neq n$ the whole term will equal 0. For $m=n$ the terms on the right hand side of $c_{ n }$ equal 1, leading to $<\phi_{ m } | f>=\sum_{ n = -\infty }^{ \infty } { c_{ n }}$.

Thank you in advance and kind regards from Germany

Comment: Look at the definition of the inner product you have, $\langle \phi_{n} \lvert \phi_{m} \rangle$. You want to get something similar to compute the coefficients. So how about multiplying both sides of the expression for $f$ by $\phi_{m}^{*}$ and integrating over the domain? That makes the left hand side $\langle \phi_{m} \lvert f \rangle$ What happens on the RHS for the cases $m \ne n$ and $m = n$? Hint: use your result from part one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to follow your hints and got somewhere close to where I wanted to be. I added the calculation to my initial post. Can I now simply omit the sum and that's the proof for $<\phi_{ m } | f>={ c_{ n }}$?

Comment: You have almost got the result, though it's not quite as simple as simply omitting the sum. You just shouldn't have the summation in the last line at all. You have shown that for every $n \ne m$ the coefficient $c_{n}$ is multiplied by a zero and so doesn't contribute to the sum; the only coefficient that doesn't vanish is $c_{m}$. Hence you have $$\langle \phi_{m} \lvert f \rangle = \dots + 0 c_{n-2} + 0 c_{n-1} + c_{m} + 0 c_{n+1} + \dots \implies \langle \phi_{m} \lvert f \rangle = c_{m}$$ and then using $m = n$, we can relabel the indices to get $\langle \phi_{n} \lvert f \rangle = c_{n}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now I got a much better understanding of this topic.